# Subtracting two totals

Tags: php

I have a table linked though mysql. I have 5 columns showing: Name, Shop, Description, Amount Owed and cost. I have written a script to tally up the totals of of "amount owed" and "cost". I am having trouble with subtracting the total "cost" from the total "Amount Owed".

Here is my code below.

```
<div>
        <table id="datatables" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Shop</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount due</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
       </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['category']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['subject']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['custom1']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['custom2']?></td>
              </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT custom1, SUM(custom1) FROM hesk_tickets";

                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "Total Owed". $row['custom1']. " = £". $row['SUM(custom1)'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }

                ?>  

                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT custom2, SUM(custom2) FROM hesk_tickets";

                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "Cost exVAT". $row['custom2']. " = £". $row['SUM(custom2)'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "Profit". $row['custom1 , custom2']. " = £". $row['SUM(custom1 - custom2)'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }

                ?>  

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: what exactly is `$row['custom1 , custom2']` supposed to be? While it's not invalid syntax, it's a totally WRONG way to get data from a query result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
echo "Profit". $row['custom1 , custom2']. " = £". $row['SUM(custom1 - custom2)'];
```

needs to be:

```
echo "Profit". $row['custom1']. ",".$row['custom2']." = £". $row['custom1'] - $row['custom2'];
```

and heed the advice from @h2ooooooo - go and look up better and more secure ways of using PHP/MySQL.